# Why can't these variables be moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

There seems to be a lot of missed opportunity in the C++ move semantics. I'd like to understand the rationale behind those and why the standard isn't more aggressive at defining when a variable should be moved in the following cases:

```
string f()
{
    string s;
    return s + " ";
}
```

This calls `operator+(const string&, const char*)`, not `operator+(string&&, const char*)`, I believe because `s` is an *lvalue*. Couldn't the standard say that, in the last use of a local variable in a function, the variable is to be considered movable?

I think a somewhat similar example:

```
struct A { A(string&&); };
string g()
{
    string s;
    return s; // s is moved
}
A h()
{
    string s;
    return s; // s can't be moved!
}
```

`g` uses move semantics to move the data from `s` to the return value, but `h` doesn't compile because `s` is not moved in `h`. I believe this is because the standard has a special case for `g` where it says essentially that if you return a local variable of the exact same type as the return type, the variable is moved. Why isn't the rule that if you return a local variable, it's moved, regardless of its type?

Comment: If I did `return s + "a" + s + "b"`, which `s` should be moved? It is better for things to be automatically converted to an rvalue-reference only in very obvious cases to avoid unexpected destruction from what looks like a copy.

Comment: You were mixing use of `wstring` and `char *`, I changed them all to `string` (the type is not relevant to the question anyway). Also, you say *but h doesn't compile*, `h()` should very well compile because the `A(string&)` constructor is not `explicit`, so an `A` object will be created from `s`. And, moving is not always the best option for returning a value from a function. While better than copying in most cases, NRVO probably trumps moving, and explicitly requiring moving in all those cases would inhibit NRVO.

Comment: @DavidBrown: "neither is moved" in your example would still allow for the `s` to be moved in `s + " "`. But it starts to look arbitrary.

Comment: Are you sure that in `g` the string is actually moved by the return?

Comment: @MarkB: C++11  12.8/32: "When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to
select the constructor for the copy is ﬁrst performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue". The move is eligible for elision, though, so there's no guarantee that the string is moved, it might be constructed directly into the return value instead. It is guaranteed not to be copied, since `string` does have a move ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, it's an unnecessary restriction in the current standard, which makes automatic moves depend on the availability of copy-elision.

Another example would be:

```
struct X{
  std::string s;
};

std::string foo(){
  X x;
  return x.s; // no automatic move
};
```

I opened a thread on http://isocpp.org's Future Standard Proposals forum, which can be seen [here](http://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-future-proposals?place=msg/std-proposals/07tdIbHTs-M/JalNnMlRZ6QJ). On the advice of Richard Smith, I directly mailed to Mike Miller about opening a core issue on this and got this response:

> [...] based on Richard's summary above, it does sound like a reasonable question, so I'll open an issue for it in the next revision of the issues list. Thanks.

So for C++14, all these restrictions will likely go away and everytime a local variable is returned, you'll get an automatic move.

Richard's summary btw is this:

> More concretely, [class.copy]p31 has a rule that the copy can be elided for a statement "return id-expression;" where the id-expression names a local variable, *and the variable has the same cv-unqualified type as the function's return type*. The suggestion is that we should perform an automatic move any time we have a statement "return id-expression;" where the id-expression names a local variable or function parameter, regardless of the type of the variable.

Comment: Would that cover both examples in the question, or just the second?

Comment: @Steve: Ah, just the second, I think. Things like `return expr_using_local_var;` are difficult to evaluate and it's best left alone. The user can insert a `std::move` himself there, since copy-elision (aka (N)RVO) is not applicable anyways.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yay! And aww, they still won't move subobjects like in my code snippet. :(

Comment: Yeah, I think the concerning with moving members is leaving the object in a state that will surprise its destructor, so you still need the explicit `std::move` there, to say "I know what I'm doing".

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That seems weird. If the member is accessible by anyone but the containing class itself, you have no guarantees anyways upon entering the destructor. Also, 'subobject' would include array elements, which has no problem with dtors.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure it could require a move either example, but then someone would come up with another case where they think it's "obvious" that `s` is being used for the last time, and therefore should be moved.

Ultimately you'd have the standard defining what data-flow analysis the compiler is required to perform. The authors decided to draw the line conservatively, to allow implementations to be stupid in that respect. Programmers can always write `std::move` to change a copy to a move.

Another possibility would be for the standard to say that it is unspecified whether objects are moved or copied, provided that the code doesn't use them again. That would allow the implementation to be as clever as it likes. I'm pretty sure that would be a bad idea: in practice users often don't care whether their objects are moved, but they sometimes need to work it out.

Comment: I think if s is used twice, in an expression, we could have undefined behavior (move would be put on the last one being used by the compiler, but which one that is undefined, similar to how (++i) + i has undefined value). I don't think that require complex data flow analysis... Just that the last occurence of a local variable is moveable.

Comment: @anonymous: And you don't think that would break ginormous amounts of code, if using a local variable multiple times in a return expression?